# is there a cleaner way to chain this grep pipeline without all the back slashes and still avoid having long lines?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, adb

The problem i have with this is its ugly.

```
#!/bin/bash

packages=$(\
adb shell ps | \
grep -v root | \
grep -v system | \
grep -v "android.process." | \
grep -v radio | \
grep -v "com.google.process." | \
grep -v "com.lge." | \
grep -v shell | \
grep -v NAME | \
awk '{print $NF}' | \
tr '\r' ' ' )

function nuke(){
    echo "Killing $p"
    adb shell am force-stop  "$1" &
    adb shell am stopservice "$1" &
    adb shell am kill        "$1" &
    adb shell pkill          "$1" &
    adb shell killall -9     "$1" &
}

function nuke-all(){
    for p in $packages; do
        nuke "$p" 
    done
}

nuke-all
```

Comment: If you could show samples of input and expected output in your question then we could do it in a single `awk`, kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Here is a translation of your multiple `grep` + `awk` commands where you could see we could do it in single `awk` but again not tested `adb shell ps | awk '!/root|system|android\.process\.|radio|com\.google\.process\.|com\.lge\.|shell|NAME/{gsub(/\r/,OFS);print $NF}'` Lemme know if this one command helps you?

Comment: `.` is a special character in a regex. Use `\.`. See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: In the function `nuke()` the `&` sends the action to the background. I think you want to remove them. When you only want to execute the next line when the first was successful, use `&&`, but in this case I think you only want the next line when the last failed (use `||`).

Answer (score 5):

OP's command could be done in a single command too, could you please try following, its a single `awk` command(not tested because of 
 no samples given and a direct conversion of OP's multiple grep commands too).

```
adb shell ps | 
awk '
!/root|system|android\.process\.|radio|com\.google\.process\.|com\.lge\.|shell|NAME/{
    gsub(/\r/,OFS)
    print $NF
}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can store the exceptions in an array first:

```
exceptions=(
   root
   system
   "android.process."
   radio
   "com.google.process."
   "com.lge."
   shell
   NAME
)
grep -vf <(printf "%s\n" ${exceptions[@]}) data
```

Edit:
When you don't like the strings being seen as regular extractions, use `-Fvf`.

Comment: Make it `-Fvf` since none of the search strings are regular expressions (And the periods in them *might* conceivably match the wrong thing when they're treated as REs).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove the backslashes. An unfinished pipeline will continue onto the next line.

```
packages=$(
    adb shell ps |
        grep -v root |
        grep -v system |
        grep -v "android\.process\." |
        grep -v radio |
        grep -v "com\.google\.process\." |
        grep -v "com\.lge\." |
        grep -v shell |
        grep -v NAME |
        awk '{print $NF}' |
        tr '\r' ' '
    )
```

I also added indenting to reflect the structure, and escaped the literal dots.

But as mentioned in the comments, it would be better to simplify this into a single AWK command. Or you could at least combine the grep commands:

```
exclude='root|system|android\.process\.|radio|com\.google\.process\.|com.lge\.|shell|NAME'
packages=$(
    adb shell ps |
        grep -vE "$exclude" |
        awk '{print $NF}' |
        tr '\r' ' '
    )
```

Comment: And to round the circle, you **do need** "\" chars when you don't have a `|` as the last character. ..... I like having the `|` at the front of the line as it heightens the "pipe" visual metaphor, but at the cost of extra chars in your syntax ( and of course it does require trailing "\"` chars at the end of the preceding line). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter I prefer to avoid line continuations at all costs, that's why I didn't even mention it.

Comment: fair enough! and each to their own. Cheers!